# Select graphql data with useResult on nested properties

Tags: typescript, vue.js, graphql, apollo-client, vue-composition-api

We have a graphql query that is executed like this:

```js
// rosterDispatchGroup.query.graphql
query rosterDispatchGroup($fromDate: DateTime!) {
  rosterDispatchGroup(fromDate: $fromDate) {
    ... on ApiError {
      message
    }
    ... on RosterDispatchGroupArray {
      data {
        date
        dispatchGroup
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And returns a data `array` (or a message in case of `ApiError`):

```json
{
  "data": {
    "rosterDispatchGroup": {
      "data": [
        {
          "date": "2020-10-28",
          "dispatchGroup": [ "A" ]
        }
    ]
}
```

To use this data in the Vue template we do this:

```js
import { useResult } from '@vue/apollo-composable'
import { defineComponent } from '@vue/composition-api'
import { useRosterDispatchGroupQuery } from 'src/graphql/generated/operations'

export default defineComponent({
  setup() {
    const { result, loading, error } = useRosterDispatchGroupQuery(
      () => { return { fromDate: new Date() } },
    )

    const dispatchGroups = useResult( result, [],
      (data) => data.rosterDispatchGroup.data // property data does not exist on type
    )
    return { dispatchGroups, loading, error }
  },
})
```

This code works fine but we get the following typescript error message:

[image: roperty 'data' does not exist on type '({ __typename?: "RosterDispatchGroupArray" | undefined; } & { data?: ({ __typename?: "RosterDispatchGroup" | undefined; } & Pick<RosterDispatchGroup, "date" | "dispatchGroup">)[] | null | undefined; }) | ({ ...; } & Pick<...>)'. Property 'data' does not exist on type '{ __typename?: "ApiError" | undefined; } & Pick<ApiError, "message">'.Vetur(2339)]

What is the correct way to [nitpick the result](https://v4.apollo.vuejs.org/guide-composable/query.html#useresult) with `useResult` and avoid a typescript error? We used [graphql-codegen](https://graphql-code-generator.com/docs/plugins/typescript-vue-apollo) to generated the required typescript code and we used [this tutorial](https://blog.logrocket.com/handling-graphql-errors-like-a-champ-with-unions-and-interfaces/) for inspiration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. we only needed to check the `__typename` property before returning the object data 'array':

```js
export default defineComponent({
  setup() {
    const dispatchGroups = useResult(result, [], (data) => {
      if (data.rosterDispatchGroup.__typename === 'RosterDispatchGroupArray') {
        return data.rosterDispatchGroup.data
      }
    })

    const apiError = useResult(result, null, (data) => {
      if (data.rosterDispatchGroup.__typename === 'ApiError') {
        return data.rosterDispatchGroup
      }
    })
```